# Dotnet core automapper orderItems

Tags: asp.net-core, automapper, automapper-4

Now I am creating a website where you can place orders.

There we have Order, OrderItem and Item.

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }  
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
    public int TotalPrice { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
     public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public double TotalPrice { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public double TotalPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Upon creation of the order I will receive:

```
{
    "orderItems": [
        {
            "itemId": 1,
            "count": 4
        }
    ]
}
```

and I have added in controller:

```
 var userFromRepo = await _repo.GetUser (userId);
 OrderForCreationDto.UserId = userId;
 var order = _mapper.Map<Order> (OrderForCreationDto);
     // userFromRepo.Orders.Add(order);
     _repo.Add (order);

     if (await _repo.SaveAll ()) 
     {
         var OrderToReturn = _mapper.Map<OrderForCreationDto> (order);
        return Ok (OrderToReturn);
     }
```

and in automapper:

```
        CreateMap<Order, OrderForCreationDto> ();
        CreateMap<OrderItemForCreationDto, OrderItem> ()
            .ForMember (dest => dest.TotalPrice, opt => {
                opt.MapFrom (d => d.Item);
                opt.ResolveUsing (d => d.Item.Price * d.Count);
            });
```

but always the mapping for OrderItem => item is null and so its giving error inside automapper.

I know its a long question but its killing me, I would appreciate if you could help. Thank you in advance

Comment: the goal is to get total price of items by the count in each order item and adding that price to the order item

Answer (score 0):

You are using older version of Automapper. In the version 8.0 `ResolveUsing` was consolidated with `MapFrom`.
Looks like you have source and destination switched. Try code below or adding `.Reversemap()`

```
CreateMap<OrderItem, OrderItemForCreationDto> ()
    .ForMember (dest => dest.TotalPrice, opt => 
    {
        opt.MapFrom (d => d.Item);
        opt.ResolveUsing (d => d.Item.Price * d.Count);
    });
```

Comment: but for now IrderITem is Empty and i am mapping data from ORderITemForCreation to OrderItem to be able to add it to the database . all the data is available inside the OrderItemForCreation except the Item and thats where the problem is coming